# Is it possible to perform an arbitrary SELECT with ServiceStack's OrmLite?

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying to use ServiceStack OrmLite's `Db.Select<T>` method to execute an arbitrary SQL fragment that works just fine when run against the database directly.  Instead, I'm getting a SqlException out of their stack.

```
var res = Db.Select<Foo>(@"
  declare @v int = 1;
  select f.* from Foo where 1=@v;");
```

I'm generating the text at run time, and cannot use LINQ expressions.  I just want to know why this works against my database, works with a regular SqlDbConnection, but blows up in ServiceStack's OrmLite.  Can I disable whatever unhelpful parsing that they must be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OrmLite's raw `db.Sql*` API's for [querying raw SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#new-apis-to-execute-custom-sql), e.g:

```
var res = Db.SqlList<Foo>(@"
  declare @v int = 1;
  select f.* from Foo where 1=@v;");
```

Comment: I ended up pulling in Dapper for this, but I'm glad there's support in OrmLite.  Maybe I'll revisit the implementation later.  Thank you!